# Where is the atmospheric pressure equal to zero?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, atmospheric-science

Consider the following question.

[image]

My calculation is as follows.

\begin{align*}
P_C = P_A + \rho g h\\
P_A = P_C - \rho g h
\end{align*}

Because $P_C=P_0=\rho g h$ then $P_A=0$.

Is it correct that the zero atmospheric pressure occurs at A? It seems to me a bit illogical because according to other resources:

> The atmospheric pressure decreased by 1 cmHg if we climb 100 m upward.

Thus the zero pressure should be very far above the point $A$.

Comment: I would not call "atmospheric" the pressure at A. It is not in contact with the atmosphere and as DavePhd said, you can approximate it as being a vacuum (that is why you assume is zero).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it correct that the zero atmospheric pressure occurs at A?

Yes, approximately. In a real system the pressure at A would equal the vapor pressure of the liquid.

Your "other resources" are referring to the pressure of air in the atmosphere.  In the problem, the diagram represents a situation like mercury in a barometer, where the weight of the mercury forms a partial vacuum at the top of the tube.  There is no air at the top of the tube.

Comment: My understanding so far is wrong then. I thought that any points in the same horizontal line should have the same pressure.

Comment: Think of it this way, if you are at the bottom of a swimming pool, which is at the top of hill, the pressure will be much higher than in the air at the same horizontal level.  If the pool is filled with mercury, the pressure would be even higher

Comment: "any points in the same horizontal line should have the same pressure" is only valid within the same medium if you do not cross any interfaces